# Maximo anywhere - how to install certificate for applicationcenter in order to install apps on iOS?

Tags: ios, ssl, maximo-anywhere

I'm sure that someone must have done this and I hope they can share their solution here.
I have successfully installed Maximo 7.6 and built and deployed Maximo Anywhere 7.5.2 apps on mac. I can see my apps when i type the URL to the applicationcenter on my iPad. The last step, according to IBM, is: "To install applications on iOS devices, you must first configure the Application Center server with SSL".
I'm using Websphere 8.5.5 and Maximo is accessible on port 9080 (or 80, using webserver) and MobileFirst is on 9081.
If i get the certificate and install it somehow (following IBM instructions did not get me far, but that is not important, yet) - what would be the the url where i can find my applicationcenter?
At the moment i can access it on http://mycomputer:9081/applicationcenter but i can't install apps.
So, I have the following 2 questions:
1. If i secure it via SSL will it be on the same port only with https instead of http, i.e. https:/mycomputer:9081/applicationcenter?
2. Can you get the certificate from any CA at all for "mycomputer"? (tried CAcert since they are not charging, but they try to validate the name by sending email to admin@mycomputer which obviously is not going to work)
Thank you in advance.
Cheers,
Pierre

Answer (score 0):

1. No, it will be on a different port.  There should be lots of information out there on how to configure WebSphere securely that you can follow.
2. No, you actually have to use a certificate that has a valid common name built into it that matches the hostname that you're deploying to.

If you're just looking to run some development unit tests of the application, you can push the ipa to your device using ITunes or XCode instead of using the application center to install the application on your device.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Scott.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Scott. 1. I have followed IBM's documentation but they only talk about securing IBM http server port 80 (which becomes 443 in that case). I want to use certificate to secure port 9081. So if you know of any documentation "out there" please add a link to it. 2. my computer's hostname IS 'mycomputer' - so again, can that name be used or not for the certificate? 3. I can push ipa files using ITunes (which i did) - but that is not the point i'm trying to understand here. I want to know if i can get a certificate for "mycomputer" computer and how do i secure only port 9081.

Comment: You can probably not use mycomputer, as the certificate authority requires a fully qualified hostname to generate the certificate (and the device must be able to reach that fully qualified hostname.  Follow a guide like this to switch the existing 9081 port to a secure port.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810062/websphere-change-port-of-web-service-from-default-to-443

Answer (score 0):

We've had similar issues.

Created Self Signed CA via openSSL but really need one from a CA so that the certificate doesn't have to be installed onto iOS devices.

Making 9081 secure is easy enough by going into the server ports and making default secure 9081 instead of 9443 for the worklight/mobile first server

We found https://www.diawi.com/ a good way of quickly deploying the ipa to devices since its https secured rather than applicationcenter/installers.html

Comment: Interesting website, thanks for sharing the link chris.