# Websphere 8.5 http forward to https

Tags: https, websphere

I can browse my site like **http ://xxx.xxx:9080/app_name**

Actually, I want to type **http ://xxx.xxx/app_name**, and it forward to **https ://xxx.xxx:9443/app_name**

Thanks in advance.

Now browse **http ://xxx.xxx/app_name** is ok , but I still cannot route **http ://xxx.xxx/app_name** to **https ://xxx.xxx:9443/app_name**. Now I can directly type **https ://xxx.xxx:9443/app_name** to browse, but I want to from **http ://xxx.xxx/app_name** route to **https ://xxx.xxx:9443/app_name**

Comment: So you want to use default 80 port instead of 9080? Use this `http://xxx.xxx/app_name` instead of `http://xxx.xxx:9080/app_name` and be redirected to `https://xxx.xxx:9443/app_name` ?

Comment: Yes, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link for longer discussion [Websphere: security-constraint in web.xml is not enforced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25798241/3701228), but in short you need to add the following to your `web.xml` to make WAS redirect to Https:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>allApp</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>allresources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

**UPDATE**

Update based on comment.
If you want redirection from `http://xxx.xxx/app_name` to `https://xxx.xxx:9443/app_name` you need to change default http port in WAS from 9080 to 80 in addition to web.xml changes. In that case all your apps will be available on WAS without the 9080 port e.g. `http://xxx.xxx/app_name` `http://xxx.xxx/app_nameN`.
In the web admin console go to `Servers > WebSphere Application Servers > server1` , then in the right section look for `Ports` link. Click and change the `WC_defaulthost` from 9080 to 80. Save and restart the server. (make sure that 80 port is free and available before making this change).